# Ajax implementation in Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Why i am not getting any value in my controller. Please help .

## Here is my controller : welcome.php

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function ajax_process(){
        $data = array(
            'email' =>$this->input->post('email'),
            'password'=>$this->input->post('password')
        );
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

**this is my view file : welcome_mesage.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sbtn').click(function(){
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var datas = $('#myform').serialize(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/codeigniter_testing/index.php/welcome/ajax_process",
            data: {email : email, password : password},
            success:function(data){
                echo data;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**my base url:** 
$config['base_url'] = `'http://localhost/codeigniter_testing/';`

Answer (score 0):

In your code their are code error

```
success:function(data){
            echo data;
        }
```

you have add `alert` instead of `echo`.

EX:

```
 success:function(data){
            alert(data.email);
        }
```

Comment: so what i want to alert and not echo ?

Comment: also one thing is missing thare.

Comment: Didn't get you question, explain it. what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @user3537756 : You need to try Hikmat Sijapati's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sbtn').click(function(){
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        var datas = $('#myform').serialize(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/codeigniter_testing/index.php/welcome/ajax_process",
            data: {email : email, password : password},
            success:function(data){
                var result=eval(data);
                alert(result.email);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```